# Make document.ready not wait for specific DOM elements to finish loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, document

I found myself in a following situation. I need to somehow not include `<div class="article-meta-social"></div>` element and all its contents into my document.ready function. The reason is, it has links to apis from facebook, twitter, g+ etc... and Multiplied by several posts it results in a little delay before contents within document.ready function are fired off.
Therefore, what can I change in order for this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

To not wait until `.article-meta-social` and its contents are ready?

Comment: Put your code at the end of the page before </body> OR fill the social div in document ready at the end

Comment: `document.ready` should fire before everything has finished loading anyway. Unless your scripts are inline?

Comment: @Dave Thats the thing, it does, but I don't wan't it to wait until .article-meta-social is ready and fire before that.

Comment: @mplungjan Your second suggestion, I don't quiet understand what you mean, can you expand on that please.

Comment: So don't use that particular element inside the ready handler. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: @Ilya - what Graham suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(document).ready` relies on the native `DOMContentLoaded` event, which does exactly what it says - fires when the entire DOM has been parsed. So to achieve what you want, insert the contents of  `.article-meta-social` dynamically inside your ready handler. This way it won't hold up the main rendering of your page.